# Discrete vs Continuous Predictions

Tags: artificial-intelligence

The sigmoid function is defined as sigmoid(x) = 1/(1+e-x). If the score is defined by 4x1 + 5x2 - 9 = score, then which of the following points has exactly a 50% probability of being blue or red? (Choose all that are correct.)

answers:
(1,1) - (2,4) - (5,-5), (-4,5)

can someone explains how to solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im taking the same udacity course. You asked the wrong question, got the wrong answer.
its 1/1(1+e^-x)

the correct code is

```
from math import e,pow
#Equation: 4x1+5x2-9=score
#weights are 4,5 and bias is -9, find the sigmoid(x) = 1/(1+e-x).

features=[(1,1),(2,4),(5,-5),(-4,5)]
def linear_func(features):
    for x in features:
        score= 4*x[0]+ 5*x[1]-9
        y = 1 / (1 + pow(e,- score))
        print("X",x,score,y)
 #call the function
linear_func(features)
```

answer is 1,1 and -4,5

answer on udacity:
That's correct. Intuitively, if you look at the plot for a sigmoid function, the probability would always be 50% if the score evaluates to zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import e
#Equation: 4x1+5x2-9=score
#weights are 4,5 and bias is -9, find the sigmoid(x) = 1/(1+e-x).

features=[(1,1),(2,4),(5,-5),(-4,5)]
def linear_func(features):
    for x in features:
        score= 4*x[0]+ 5*x[1]-9
        y = 1 / (1 + e - score)
        print("X",x,score,y)
 #call the function
linear_func(features)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as language version, Library / SDK dependencies, etc.